# How to determine whether critical points (of the lagrangian function) are minima or maxima?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$f(x,y) = 2x+y$ subject to $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1=0$. The Lagrangian function is given by

$$
\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)=2x+y+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1),
$$

with corresponding

$$
\nabla \mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)= \begin{bmatrix}  2 + 2\lambda x \\ 1+2\lambda y \\ x^2+y^2-1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

From the latter we can see that $x=\frac{-1}{\lambda}$ and $y=\frac{-1}{2\lambda}$, which we can substitute into $x^2+y^2=1$ to obtain $\lambda = \pm\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$. Meaning that $x = \pm \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $y= \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. We find the critical points $(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})$ and $(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}})$.

I am confused on how I should proceed to check wether these points or minima or maxima? I know the Hessian is involved, but which one?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis It is not a duplicate. My question is not on *how* to find critical points, its *what* these critical points are, i.e. what kind of extrema. The *possibile* duplicate does answer the former, leaving the latter unanswered.

Comment: this just shows you didn't read the comments, via compactness you know one is minimal one is maximal and via the signs you get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general when optimizing $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=0$, you solve the problem $\nabla f(x)=\lambda \nabla g(x)$ and the critical points  can be checked by the bordered Hessian matrix:

$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & g_x & g_y\\
g_x & f_{xx}+\lambda g_{xx} & f_{xy}+\lambda g_{xy}\\
g_y & f_{yx}+\lambda g_{yx} & f_{yy}+\lambda g_{yy}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Define $h:=\det(H)$. If $h>0$ at the critical point, you're at a maximum and if $h<0$ you're at a minimum. Equivalently, you can replace all instances of $g$ in the above Hessian with $-g$ so that the derivatives in the bottom right square become those of $f-\lambda g$. Indeed, consider expanding $f-\lambda g$ around each critical point taking into account that you are moving along $g$.

Answer (score 2):

You've done the hard part. Now check the values of $f(x,y)$ at the two points $(x,y) = (\pm 2/\sqrt{5}, \pm 1/\sqrt{5})$. Since $$f(\pm 2/\sqrt{5}, \pm 1/\sqrt{5}) = 2(\pm2/\sqrt5) \pm1/\sqrt5 = \pm\sqrt{5},$$
you can conclude that $f$ is maximized at $(2/\sqrt5,1/\sqrt5)$ and minimized at $(-2/\sqrt5,-1/\sqrt5)$.

Edit: To clarify, the reason this is enough to make the above conclusion is that the constraint space $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a closed curve and $f$ is continuous. Therefore $f$ attains a maximum and minimum on this space, and you can conclude they are the points you solved for using Lagrange multipliers. Since you only found two points, the function $f$ must be maximized at one and minimized at the other. The above work checks which is which.

In general, you need to use a [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) to determine where you have extrema.

Comment: This doesn't conclude that the critical points are min/max of the constrained optimization, only that one is below the other

Comment: It's not enough that $x^2+y^2=1$ is compact. The key property is that it forms a closed curve along with the fact that $f$ is continuous from which the conclusion follows.

Comment: @AlexR.: You're right, sorry. Thanks for pointing this out! I'll correct it. That's what I get for writing solutions early in the morning! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately $\{x^2+y^2-1=0\}$ is compact and $f$ continuous thus $f$ must have a min and max.  Just compare the values of $f$ at the critical values.  In this case the Hessian is not needed.

Comment: Well, they can.  But since $f$ is bounded to have a min and a max on a compact set, some critical values are bounded to correspond to the min, some to the min and we don't care about the other values.

Comment: But the key fact about the constraint is that it forms a closed curve. An interval $[0,1]$ is perfectly well compact but a constraint optimization on it may not give the true min/max

Comment: @AlexR. You can't formulate a constraint optimization for $[0,1]$, can you ?

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis: of course you can. You can formulate it on any curve segment you wish, except you're just looking for critical points inside whatever interval it's in. I know it's kind of a moot point, that mostly you'll get closed curves if you have a constraint (hence the compactness *is* pretty much enough) but it's not entirely correct.

Comment: @AlexR. I mean in the sense of lagrange

Comment: @AlexR. In case the curve is not closed you'll find the max and min in the interior points of the curve or on it's end points.  So since in our case there are no end points ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: that's exactly the point I'm making. Sorry for being pedantic.

Comment: You have not been pedantic enough.  You have also take in account the points were the constraint is not differentiable, as in $\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-y^2}=0$.